# filemaker api and fmRESTRor find with OR condition

Tags: php, filemaker

Coming from an sql background and trying to learn FileMaker using fmRESTor in php to communicate with the api.  If I had the following table called 'animals' in an sql databae:

```
field1   |    field2  |   field3
------------------------------
dog      |    mammal  |   woof
cat      |    mammal  |   meow
canary   |    bird    |   tweet
```

I would do `select * from animals where field1 like '%og%' or field3 = 'tweet'` and get back 2 rows

```
field1   |    field2  |   field3
------------------------------
dog      |    mammal  |   woof
canary   |    bird    |   tweet
```

So how would I do that in fmRESTor or the FM api?  It looks like findRecords() is using like for each individual field and then AND to combine them.  I can set just "field1": "og" and it finds dog, but "field1: "og", "field3": "tweet" returns no records.

Any ideas?  Or do I just have to do two finds, combine the results, and eliminate duplicates?

thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with fmRESTor. In Filemaker itself, a find command needs to have two separate requests in order to perform an OR find. In the Data API this would look like `{"query":[{"field1":"og"},{"field3":"tweet"}]}`. -- P.S. Are you sure "og" finds "dog"? The default find finds "words that start with ...". You would need to search for "*og" in order to find "dog".

Comment: This is closer to the real world:
````{ "limit": "10000",
"query": [
  { "title": "lin" },
  { "author": "lin" },
  { "container": "envelope" }
]}````

Comment: silly comment rules.  The above query returns books titled "Skyline" with container: "Envelope" and books titled: "Lining", container:"Box".  So it is definitely searching for *lin* case insensitive.  As the query gets more complicated I'll want to do this AND ( ( hello or world) OR (baz OR foobar OR foobaz) ) to get back this-word, this-foobaz, this-hello-baz.  I think I need some more test data to better check it out.

Comment: I am afraid I did not understand the "more complicated" example. If you need help with this, please edit your question and explain in more detail. Keep in mind that not all possible combinations of criteria are possible (or practical) to achieve within a single find command; in some cases you would run a script that performs an initial find, then constrains/extends the found set.

Comment: I think what I want to do is treat FileMaker as if it were a regular sql database like mysql, postgresql, oracle, or mssql.  And that isn't going to work.  I think the best/fastest solution is to do mulitple finds and then remove the duplicates or results that don't fit the pattern I need.

Thanks!